# (ConTeXt) Changing to garamond or other typefaces

Tags: fonts, context

As far as I understood changing the typeface from the default is hard in ConTeXt. Here is my example of using not the default typeface - first question: Is this the correct way?:

```
    \mainlanguage   [de]

%\usetypescript[Garamond][default]
%\setupbodyfont[Garamond,15pt]

\definepapersize[MyBook][A5]
\setuppapersize[MyBook][A5] % Prints on paper the size of MyBook
%\setuppapersize[MyBook][A4]

% Fonts & Typography
\definefontfeature[default][default][expansion=quality,protrusion=quality]
\setupalign[hz,hanging]

\usetypescript[palatino]
\setupbodyfont[palatino,10pt]
\setupbodyfontenvironment   [default][em=italic] % use italic as em, not slanted

\setuplayout[location=middle,
  topspace=1cm,
  bottomspace=1.5cm,
  width=middle,
  cutspace=2.6cm,
  backspace=1.3cm,
  height=fit,
  rightmargin=2cm,
  leftmargin=1cm,
  rightmargindistance=0.4cm,
  leftmargindistance=0.2cm,
  footer=1.2cm,
  grid=yes]

\starttext
This is a test text.
\stoptext
```

Now if I change from palatino to garamond by setting

```
\usetypescript[garamond]
    \setupbodyfont[garamond,10pt]
```

then ConTeXt goes back to its Standard Computer Modern, how to change to garamond?

Comment: Your example code is not minimal. Setting the layout, language or paper is not related to your question at all. Have a look at [Wiki - Fonts in LuaTeX,](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Fonts_in_LuaTeX#Using_fonts) especially the `simplefonts` module.

Comment: Which Garamond font are you using? Afaict the minimals don’t ship with an official typescript for any of the Garamond variants, so it’s no wonder your example fails. If you are lucky, Wolfgang may have one ready for you edition in his [typescript collection](https://bitbucket.org/wolfs/typescripts). Else in order to [write a typescript](http://context.aanhet.net/svn/contextman/context-reference/en/co-fonts.pdf) more information is needed: which file contains which face etc.

Comment: Ok, with `\usemodule[simplefonts] \setmainfont[helvetica]` I can change it to helvetica, but now `\definefontfeature[default][default][expansion=quality,protrusion=quality]
\setupalign[hz,hanging]` has no effect. That may be related to the typescript, which is needed, correct? If so, which other than default and Palatino are supported?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to use fonts with ConTeXt is to use the simplefonts module.

For testing, I am using [EB Garamond](https://github.com/georgd/EB-Garamond). (You may need to run `mtxrun --script fonts --reload` to refresh the font database after you install the font).

```
\setuppapersize[A6]

\usemodule  [simplefonts][size=10pt]
\setmainfont[EB Garamond 12][expansion=quality,protrusion=quality]

\setupalign [hanging] 

\showframe % To show protrusion

\starttext
\input ward
\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Two questions: First, how can I install this font in Windows with protrusion? And second: Where can I find more font, which support protrusion?

Comment: ConTeXt should be able to fibd the font in the default windows font directory.  So just install the font the normal way and reload the font database. AFAIU, all (latin script based) fonts support protrusion.